# Is there any way to detect suddenly closed tabs and restore them on iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, safari

Today I found out that many of opened tabs on my iPad Safari are gone. Yesterday there were 50+ tabs on Safari but for some reasons now it is 14.

It is very frustrating so I tried to restore the data from my yesterday’s backup, but found that on iOS I can only backup from the most recent backup, which happened in the morning.

So I could not restore the backup from yesterday’s, but now I don’t know there is any way to restore the opened tabs, or at least detect which pages they are in order to manually open them again one by one. Is there any way to restore them?

Comment: See this relevant answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394127/119271

Comment: This might be considered a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29434/ However, this might be considered to be an issue of disappearing tabs rather than just a how-to question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long ago they were closed, you might be able to see them in a list an open them (one by one).

[image]

1. Tap the lower right button to view the list of tabs open.
2. **Tap and hold** the plus button to show recently closed tabs.

This does not work for private tabs.

Comment: I know it, but it's synced with other devices, so it is practically impossible to get the exact 40-something tabs from 10,000+ history.

Comment: The list of recently closed tabs is not synced across devices. **Holding the plus button** shows the most recently closed tabs in the order they were closed for this device only.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was confused. But anyway it did not work, since there is no longer shown any tabs on the icon... as I said, I didn't close those tabs manually.

Comment: Dang. I was hoping my advice would be relevant for not just closed tabs but tabs that were "lost". Sounds like the app had a wobble. If it's not there, I can't think of another way to get the data back that I know will work. However, there is a small chance that a backup of the device would contain the list. If you have an iCloud or iTunes backup, you could to erase and restore your phone (or another) to that specific date/time. There are some tools to browse iTunes backups without restoring a device too, but I'm not familiar with them. Good luck.

Comment: I restored from my iCloud backup but since it only keeps the most recent one the restored data already lost them. I don’t use iTunes any more... anyway thanks for the answer.